# ArchUnit: how to check for extension of an interface?

Tags: archunit

I have a package for which I want to check that all classes (these are entities that can get shipped over the net) do indeed implement the interface "java.io.Serializable".
So I defined myself a rule like so (the actual rule has a few excludes but these are not relevant here):

```
@ArchTest
void checkSerializability(JavaClasses classes) {
    ArchRule rule = ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
        .that().resideInAnyPackage("..entities..")
        .should().implement(Serializable.class)
        ;
    rule.check(classes);
}
```

That rule works fine, except that a few classes implement a common interface that *extends* Serializable, i.e.:

```
interface IAction extends Serializable {
    ... some methods to be implemented declared here ...
}
```

The above ArchUnit-rule complains that this interface(-class) does not implement Serializable.
In a sense that is true - strictly speaking it doesn't *implement* it, it just *extends* it.

But I didn't find an `extends(<class>)`-method, so I can not phrase this condition as `implements(Serializable.class).or().extends(Serializable.class)`.

So, how can can I teach ArchUnit to accept that interface as "implementing" Serializable and hence as valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me cite the JavaDoc: [`ClassesShould.implement`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#implement(java.lang.Class)) *asserts that classes implement a certain interface. Note that this only matches non-interface classes that implement the supplied interface type (compare [`JavaClass.Predicates.implement(Class)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.Predicates.html#implement(java.lang.Class))). For general assignability see [`beAssignableTo`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.2.1/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#beAssignableTo(java.lang.Class))*, which in turn
*asserts that classes are assignable to a certain type (compare [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) terminology). A simple example for this predicate would be:*

```
   assignableTo(Object.class).test(importedStringClass); // → returns true
   assignableTo(String.class).test(importedStringClass); // → returns true
   assignableTo(List.class).test(importedStringClass);   // → returns false
```

So you can use

```java
    ArchRule rule = ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
        .that().resideInAnyPackage("..entities..")
        .should().beAssignableTo(Serializable.class);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had considered that but had found it a bit odd. But it seems the way to go and it *does* work.

Comment: What seems odd to you, specifically?